# What does "Hesek" and "spricht" mean in German

Tags: translation, phrase, german-to-english

This is on a grandparents tombstone. What does it say?

> Hesek 37, 12  so spricht der herr siehe, ich will eure graeben aufthun und will euch mein volk aus denselben herausholen

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange! While your question has already gotten answers, I would like to warmly welcome you to take a [tour] of this site and visit the [help] if any questions about technical things here remain. Hope you enjoy your stay!

Comment: Also, *spricht* is the third person singular of *sprechen*. A literal translation would be *speaks*, but in this context, a better translation is *says*.

Answer (score 10):

"Hesek" is an abbreviation for "Hesekiel" (Ezekiel), and it is a [quote from the Bible](http://www.bibel-online.net/buch/luther_1912/hesekiel/37/#12)

> Darum weissage und sprich zu ihnen: So spricht der Herr, HERR: Siehe, ich will eure Gräber auftun und will euch, mein Volk, aus denselben herausholen und euch ins Land Israel bringen.

The corresponding verse in the [King James Bible](http://www.biblestudytools.com/kjv/ezekiel/37.html) reads:

> Therefore prophesy and say unto them, Thus saith the Lord GOD; Behold, O my people, I will open your graves, and cause you to come up out of your graves, and bring you into the land of Israel.

Hence you see, *So **spricht** der Herr* means *Thus **saith** the LORD*.

Comment: "So spricht der Herr, HERR" looks like a mistake. The Schlachter translation from the same site has "So spricht Gott, der HERR".

Comment: @dirkt "Looks like", yes, and surely it is debatable. But given that the phrase "Herr, HERR" also appears in verses 3,5, 19 and 21 I would say Luther intended it to translate it this way.

Comment: @dirkt: Die Übersetzung ist korrekt, bzw. so üblich. im hebräischen Originaltext http://www.bibleserver.com/text/EU.OT/Hesekiel37 steht zunächst das Wort "Herr" und danach JHWH, also der Eigenname Gottes, der aber in den meisten Übersetzungen nur ausnahmsweise mit "Jahwe" wiedergegeben wird. Vgl dazu die Anmerkung zu http://www.bibleserver.com/text/EU/1.Mose4 1 Mose 4.26 in der Einheitsübersetzung.

Comment: In der Lutherschen Orthographie:  Darumb weissage / vnd sprich zu jnen / so spricht der HErr HERR / Sihe / ich wil ewre Greber auffthun / vnd wil euch / mein Volck / aus den selben er aus holen / vnd euch ins land Jsrael bringen. Vgl. http://lutherbibel.net/